# How to add files to dotfile-castle with homesick?

Tags: linux, dotfiles

So I've setup my dotfiles repo on github and installed [homesick](https://github.com/technicalpickles/homesick) to manage my dotfiles. So now I happend to have a clone of the repo on my local machine but also a cloned CASTLE (~/.homesick/repo/myrepo). I've read the documentation but I don't seem to understand how the updating of the CASTLE is supposed to work.

I'm currently adding files to my git-repo clone adding files as I please and then pushing them. I seem to be able to change files and commit the changes however I'm having trouble adding files to my dotfiles via homesick. Basically I'm wondering/looking for something like:

```
homesick add files
```

Answer (score 2):

To add files to your castle you just do

```
homesick track <FILE> <CASTLE>
```

This will move the file to your castle and create a symlink.

You also don't have to create a separate repo of your castle outside of your `~/.homesick` directory. To initiate a new castle, you just do

```
# create castle
homesick generate ~/.homesick/repos/<CASTLE>

# enter castle directory
homesick cd <CASTLE>

# add a git remote
git remote add <REMOTE>
```

See also the [homesick readme](https://github.com/technicalpickles/homesick) and

```
homesick help
```